# why leetcode is producing different result than pycharm and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, permutation

I copied pasted and used the same input for the method, I get the correct result on my machine but leetcode is producing different result for the same code. this is the code on leetcode for permutuation sequence

```
class Solution(object):
    def getPermutation(self, n, k):
        list_ = []
        my_num = ''
        for i in range(n):
            list_.append(str(i + 1))
        fact = 1
        n_f = n
        k_f = k
        for i in range(n_f):
            fact *= (i+1)
        diveded = int(fact/n_f)
        if n_f == n:
            no = (k/diveded)
            if int(no) == no:
                no -= 1
                no = int(no)
            else:
                no = int(no)
            my_num += list_[no]
            list_.remove(list_[no])
            n_f -= 1
        while len(my_num) < n:
            fact = 1
            for i in range(n_f):
                fact *= (i + 1)
            no_ = int((k_f-1)%diveded)
            no = int(no_/fact)
            if int(no) == no and no_ > 0:
                no -= 1
                no = int(no)
            else:
                no = int(no)
            used = 0
            for i in range(len(my_num)):
                if int(my_num[i]) < int(list_[no]) and no > 0:


                    used += 1
            no -= used

            diveded = int(fact / n_f)

            while list_[no] in my_num:
                no += 1
            else:
                my_num += list_[no]
                list_.remove(list_[no])
                n_f -= 1
        else:
            return my_num




solu = Solution()
print(solu.getPermutation(3,3))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i78102751/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you chose Python instead of Python3 as the language on leetcode. You are currently running your code on version 2.7.18 which behave differently than the more recent version.